# to have so far gone + past participle

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Although cows are famed for their ability to forecast rain hours advance, their talent for navigating **has so far gone overlooked**.

1. Is that an idiomatic grammar construction or simply Present Perfect + past participle?
2. It's not clear for me what sense the word "gone" makes.

Answer (score 1):

**To go overlooked** means that something or someone  remains unnoticed,  especially when there is something noteworthy about them. Thus,

> They **have gone overlooked**.

Nobody has noticed them.

**so far** means "up until now".

Up until now, nobody has seen them and recognized that talent.

... their talent ... has, so far, gone overlooked ...

Comment: I have grown accustomed to **gone missing** but I wince at **gone overlooked**. Is that American for **been overlooked**?

Comment: @Ronald Sole: How about **gone unquestioned**?

Comment: I could live with that. I guess it's a question of what one  is familiar with. But I merely winced!

Comment: @Ronald Sole: How about **went unremarked**?

Comment: It was just a little wince. I don't think anybody noticed. (Hey, you could have the pair of us up all night!)

Comment: I'm enjoying Sunday brunch. Sorry to keep you up.  :)

Comment: What the most similar word to "gone" in such phrases can I use? remained?

Comment: @Jane: You can us **be** or **go**.   They *have been | were* overlooked is the most commonly used.  **have been** contains the idea that they were overlooked *even up to the present moment*.